# Replacing all single quotes except for ones immediately after backslash

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to web scraping, but I collected a large amount of data which I wrote to file using file.write() since I was unaware that json.dumps() existed. I'm attempting to remedy this by reformatting the data so that it can be loaded back into Python 3 as JSON.

I need to be able to replace all of the single quotes (with double quotes) in a string without replacing any of the ones that come immediately after the backslash. For example:

```
{'please':'don\'t touch friend\'s cat'}
```

Would become:

```
{"please":"don\'t touch friend\'s cat"}
```

Any other advice on reformatting would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `json.dumps(your_variable)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrote the data to a file without actually encoding it as JSON, it was most likely "encoded" as the `repr()` of your object, which should be valid Python code for simple data types. You can parse it again with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
In [3]: import ast

In [4]: ast.literal_eval(r"{'please':'don\'t touch friend\'s cat'}")
Out[4]: {'please': "don't touch friend's cat"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use negative lookbehind https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)'")
print re.sub(pattern, '"', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done fairly easy using regex with the `re` module. If you can load the data into memory as a string then you can simply execute:

`re.sub(r'(?<!\\)\'', '"', my_data_string)`

What this does is it matches all single quotes not preceded by a backslash and replaces them with double quotes. You can find more of the gory details about how this works here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html